# Getting data from localhost service with javascript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, jsonp, cors

I am working on a website that needs access to local resources, like RFID reader and some other hardware. I was thinking about writing a simple web server that would return data I need.

So that web site would access this data with JavaScript, and handle it further.

I know I cannot simply access localhost with `XMLHTTPRequest` due to same-origin policy limitations.

So is there a simple solution for this? I don't know would if I can access let say `localhost.mysite.com` if I set it locally to 127.0.0.1? 
Or maybe JSONP? Or CORS?
I am not familiar with these technologies, so I am asking how would you solve this problem, or what would be the easiest way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably best off making [a packaged Chrome app](http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/extensions/apps/about_apps.html) to do something like this. You will then be able to run it as a regular website experience, but with the right "permissions" setting in the manifest, it will be able to access any domain, including localhost.

It would require anyone using it to "install it", which is just a one-click operation.

Alternatively, if you can control the localhost servers, you can have them output JSONP or the correct CORS headers. Basically, if you want to communicate between any two domains (which includes localhost) on the regular web (ie not including special web apps like Chrome's packaged apps), they both need to provide consent for it.

Comment: Thank you...Chrome app seems very promising, do you maybe know will it run on all platforms? Can I install it in Chrome for android? For example, reading from usb on android would it work?

Comment: It will work on all PC platforms (win/linux/osx), but so far, Chrome for Android doesn't support extensions or packaged apps. Firefox does support extensions, so it's quite possible Chrome will do likewise in the future.